# I can not select Application Type in Pentaho 8.3 Kettle

Tags: pentaho

Hi I tried calling an API with Pentaho Data Integration v8.3. However, in my version I can not select the application type in the rest client properties (it is grayed out). I was wondering if anyone can give me a hint on where I could change the application type to JSON.

Below is my screenshot.

I would really appreciate the help.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select a different HTTP method first (e.g. POST)